# How to add linebreak while printing variable in HTML

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am trying to add linebreaks after each para as shown below in the Google sheet screenshot.

[image]

Basically, I have stored this cell as a variable and added it to my HTML file.
But, when I try to send mail, it pastes the `<br>` tag instead of adding linebreak.

Attaching screenshot of HTML code as well.

[image]

Please help, thanks.

HTML and Google Appscripts code attached below -

```js
function Code() {
  
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const ws = ss.getSheetByName("MailDetails");
  
  var heading = ws.getRange("B2").getValue();
  var subheading = ws.getRange("C2").getValue();
  var body = ws.getRange("J2").getValue();
  var footer = ws.getRange("K2").getValue();
  var impfield1 = ws.getRange("D2").getValue();
  var impfield2 = ws.getRange("E2").getValue();
  var impfield3 = ws.getRange("F2").getValue();
  var fieldvalue1 = ws.getRange("G2").getValue();
  var fieldvalue2 = ws.getRange("H2").getValue();
  var fieldvalue3 = ws.getRange("I2").getValue();
  
  var file1 = DriveApp.getFilesByName('SGB 2021-22.pdf').next()
  Logger.log(file1)

  const htmlTemplate = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("SGB I.html");
          htmlTemplate.heading = heading;
          htmlTemplate.subheading = subheading;
          htmlTemplate.body = body;
          htmlTemplate.footer = footer;
          htmlTemplate.impfield1 = impfield1;
          htmlTemplate.impfield2 = impfield2;
          htmlTemplate.impfield3 = impfield3;
          htmlTemplate.fieldvalue1 = fieldvalue1;
          htmlTemplate.fieldvalue2 = fieldvalue2;
          htmlTemplate.fieldvalue3 = fieldvalue3;

  const htmlforemail = htmlTemplate.evaluate().getContent();
  
  GmailApp.sendEmail("mayank.agarwal@aumcap.com",
  "SGB 2021-22 Series I issue opens today!",
  "SGB 2021-22 Series I issue opens today!",
  {attachments: file1,
  htmlBody: htmlforemail},
  )
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
 <head> 
  <meta charset="UTF-8"> 
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport"> 
  <meta name="x-apple-disable-message-reformatting"> 
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"> 
  <meta content="telephone=no" name="format-detection"> 
  <title>Product note</title> 
  <!--[if (mso 16)]>
    <style type="text/css">
    a {text-decoration: none;}
    </style>
    <![endif]--> 
  <!--[if gte mso 9]><style>sup { font-size: 100% !important; }</style><![endif]--> 
  <!--[if gte mso 9]>
<xml>
    <o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
    <o:AllowPNG></o:AllowPNG>
    <o:PixelsPerInch>96</o:PixelsPerInch>
    </o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
</xml>
<![endif]--> 
  <!--[if !mso]><!-- --> 
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,400i,700,700i" rel="stylesheet"> 
  <!--<![endif]--> 
  <style type="text/css">
#outlook a {
    padding:0;
}
.es-button {
    mso-style-priority:100!important;
    text-decoration:none!important;
}
a[x-apple-data-detectors] {
    color:inherit!important;
    text-decoration:none!important;
    font-size:inherit!important;
    font-family:inherit!important;
    font-weight:inherit!important;
    line-height:inherit!important;
}
.es-desk-hidden {
    display:none;
    float:left;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:0;
    max-height:0;
    line-height:0;
    mso-hide:all;
}
[data-ogsb] .es-button {
    border-width:0!important;
    padding:10px 20px 10px 20px!important;
}
@media only screen and (max-width:600px) {p, ul li, ol li, a { line-height:150%!important } h1 { font-size:30px!important; text-align:center; line-height:120% } h2 { font-size:26px!important; text-align:center; line-height:120% } h3 { font-size:20px!important; text-align:center; line-height:120% } .es-header-body h1 a, .es-content-body h1 a, .es-footer-body h1 a { font-size:30px!important } .es-header-body h2 a, .es-content-body h2 a, .es-footer-body h2 a { font-size:26px!important } .es-header-body h3 a, .es-content-body h3 a, .es-footer-body h3 a { font-size:20px!important } .es-menu td a { font-size:16px!important } .es-header-body p, .es-header-body ul li, .es-header-body ol li, .es-header-body a { font-size:16px!important } .es-content-body p, .es-content-body ul li, .es-content-body ol li, .es-content-body a { font-size:16px!important } .es-footer-body p, .es-footer-body ul li, .es-footer-body ol li, .es-footer-body a { font-size:16px!important } .es-infoblock p, .es-infoblock ul li, .es-infoblock ol li, .es-infoblock a { font-size:12px!important } *[class="gmail-fix"] { display:none!important } .es-m-txt-c, .es-m-txt-c h1, .es-m-txt-c h2, .es-m-txt-c h3 { text-align:center!important } .es-m-txt-r, .es-m-txt-r h1, .es-m-txt-r h2, .es-m-txt-r h3 { text-align:right!important } .es-m-txt-l, .es-m-txt-l h1, .es-m-txt-l h2, .es-m-txt-l h3 { text-align:left!important } .es-m-txt-r img, .es-m-txt-c img, .es-m-txt-l img { display:inline!important } .es-button-border { display:block!important } a.es-button, button.es-button { font-size:20px!important; display:block!important; border-width:10px 0px 10px 0px!important } .es-adaptive table, .es-left, .es-right { width:100%!important } .es-content table, .es-header table, .es-footer table, .es-content, .es-footer, .es-header { width:100%!important; max-width:600px!important } .es-adapt-td { display:block!important; width:100%!important } .adapt-img { width:100%!important; height:auto!important } .es-m-p0 { padding:0px!important } .es-m-p0r { padding-right:0px!important } .es-m-p0l { padding-left:0px!important } .es-m-p0t { padding-top:0px!important } .es-m-p0b { padding-bottom:0!important } .es-m-p20b { padding-bottom:20px!important } .es-mobile-hidden, .es-hidden { display:none!important } tr.es-desk-hidden, td.es-desk-hidden, table.es-desk-hidden { width:auto!important; overflow:visible!important; float:none!important; max-height:inherit!important; line-height:inherit!important } tr.es-desk-hidden { display:table-row!important } table.es-desk-hidden { display:table!important } td.es-desk-menu-hidden { display:table-cell!important } .es-menu td { width:1%!important } table.es-table-not-adapt, .esd-block-html table { width:auto!important } table.es-social { display:inline-block!important } table.es-social td { display:inline-block!important } }
</style> 
 </head> 
 <body style="width:100%;font-family:arial, 'helvetica neue', helvetica, sans-serif;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;padding:0;Margin:0"> 
  <div class="es-wrapper-color" style="background-color:#F6F6F6"> 
   <!--[if gte mso 9]>
            <v:background xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="t">
                <v:fill type="tile" color="#f6f6f6"></v:fill>
            </v:background>
        <![endif]--> 
   <table class="es-wrapper" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;padding:0;Margin:0;width:100%;height:100%;background-repeat:repeat;background-position:center top"> 
     <tr> 
      <td valign="top" style="padding:0;Margin:0"> 
       <table class="es-header" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;table-layout:fixed !important;width:100%;background-color:transparent;background-repeat:repeat;background-position:center top"> 
         <tr> 
          <td align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="padding:0;Margin:0;background-color:#FFFFFF"> 
           <table class="es-header-body" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#ffffff" align="center" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;background-color:#FFFFFF;border-top:8px solid #EFEFEF;border-right:2px solid #EFEFEF;border-left:2px solid #EFEFEF;width:600px"> 
             <tr> 
              <td class="esdev-adapt-off" align="left" style="Margin:0;padding-bottom:5px;padding-top:10px;padding-right:15px;padding-left:20px"> 
               <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="esdev-mso-table" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;width:561px"> 
                 <tr> 
                  <td class="esdev-mso-td" valign="top" style="padding:0;Margin:0"> 
                   <table class="es-left" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="left" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;float:left"> 
                     <tr> 
                      <td class="es-m-p0r" valign="top" align="center" style="padding:0;Margin:0;width:176px"> 
                       <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" role="presentation" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px"> 
                         <tr> 
                          <td align="center" style="padding:0;Margin:0;font-size:0px"><a target="_blank" href="http://www.aumcap.com" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;text-decoration:underline;color:#1376C8;font-size:14px"><img src="https://ndilga.stripocdn.email/content/guids/CABINET_7728732573bb6fb09b1911bf5b2daa3a/images/8361621066250507.png" alt style="display:block;border:0;outline:none;text-decoration:none;-ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic" width="176"></a></td> 
                         </tr> 
                       </table></td> 
                     </tr> 
                   </table></td> 
                  <td class="esdev-mso-td" valign="top" style="padding:0;Margin:0"> 
                   <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="right" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px"> 
                     <tr> 
                      <td align="left" style="padding:0;Margin:0;width:360px"> 
                       <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" role="presentation" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px"> 
                         <tr> 
                          <td align="right" style="padding:0;Margin:0;padding-top:35px;font-size:0"> 
                           <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="es-table-not-adapt es-social" role="presentation" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px"> 
                             <tr> 
                              <td align="center" valign="top" style="padding:0;Margin:0;padding-right:10px"><a target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/AUMCap" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;text-decoration:underline;color:#1376C8;font-size:14px"><img title="Facebook" src="https://ndilga.stripocdn.email/content/assets/img/social-icons/circle-colored/facebook-circle-colored.png" alt="Fb" width="24" height="24" style="display:block;border:0;outline:none;text-decoration:none;-ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic"></a></td> 
                              <td align="center" valign="top" style="padding:0;Margin:0"><a target="_blank" href="https://www.twitter.com/AUMCap" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;text-decoration:underline;color:#1376C8;font-size:14px"><img title="Twitter" src="https://ndilga.stripocdn.email/content/assets/img/social-icons/circle-colored/twitter-circle-colored.png" alt="Tw" width="24" height="24" style="display:block;border:0;outline:none;text-decoration:none;-ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic"></a></td> 
                             </tr> 
                           </table></td> 
                         </tr> 
                       </table></td> 
                     </tr> 
                   </table></td> 
                 </tr> 
               </table></td> 
             </tr> 
           </table></td> 
         </tr> 
       </table> 
       <table class="es-content" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;table-layout:fixed !important;width:100%"> 
         <tr> 
          <td align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="padding:0;Margin:0;background-color:#FFFFFF"> 
           <table class="es-content-body" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#ffffff" align="center" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;background-color:#FFFFFF;border-right:2px solid #EFEFEF;border-left:2px solid #EFEFEF;width:600px"> 
             <tr> 
              <td align="left" background="https://ndilga.stripocdn.email/content/guids/CABINET_7728732573bb6fb09b1911bf5b2daa3a/images/49801621066184983.png" style="padding:0;Margin:0;padding-left:15px;padding-right:15px;padding-top:20px;background-image:url(https://ndilga.stripocdn.email/content/guids/CABINET_7728732573bb6fb09b1911bf5b2daa3a/images/49801621066184983.png);background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position:center top;background-color:#FEF6F0" bgcolor="#fef6f0"> 
               <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px"> 
                 <tr> 
                  <td valign="top" align="center" style="padding:0;Margin:0;width:566px"> 
                   <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" role="presentation" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px"> 
                     <tr> 
                      <td align="left" style="padding:0;Margin:0;padding-right:10px"><p style="Margin:0;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-family:'lucida sans unicode', 'lucida grande', sans-serif;line-height:21px;color:#333333;font-size:14px"><br></p><h2 style="Margin:0;line-height:36px;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-family:arial, 'helvetica neue', helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:24px;font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;color:#DAA520"><br></h2><h2 style="Margin:0;line-height:48px;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-family:'trebuchet ms', 'lucida grande', 'lucida sans unicode', 'lucida sans', tahoma, sans-serif;font-size:32px;font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;color:#DAA520"><strong><?= heading ?></strong></h2><p style="Margin:0;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-family:lato, 'helvetica neue', helvetica, arial, sans-serif;line-height:21px;color:#333333;font-size:14px"><br></p><p style="Margin:0;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-family:lato, 'helvetica neue', helvetica, arial, sans-serif;line-height:26px;color:#333333;font-size:17px"><strong><span style="color:#000080"><?= subheading ?></p><p style="Margin:0;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-family:lato, 'helvetica neue', helvetica, arial, sans-serif;line-height:24px;color:#333333;font-size:16px;text-align:justify"><?= body ?></p>
                     </tr> 
                   </table></td> 
                 </tr> 
               </table></td> 
             </tr> 
           </table></td> 
         </tr> 
       </table> 
       <table class="es-footer" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;table-layout:fixed !important;width:100%;background-color:transparent;background-repeat:repeat;background-position:center top"> 
         <tr> 
          <td align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="padding:0;Margin:0;background-color:#FFFFFF"> 
           <table class="es-footer-body" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#ffffff" align="center" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;background-color:#FFFFFF;border-right:2px solid #EFEFEF;border-left:2px solid #EFEFEF;width:600px;border-bottom:8px solid #EFEFEF"> 
             <tr> 
              <td align="left" style="padding:0;Margin:0;padding-top:10px;padding-left:20px;padding-right:20px"> 
               <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px"> 
                 <tr> 
                  <td align="left" style="padding:0;Margin:0;width:556px"> 
                   <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" role="presentation" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px"> 
                     <tr> 
                      <td align="center" style="padding:0;Margin:0"><h4 style="Margin:0;line-height:120%;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-family:arial, 'helvetica neue', helvetica, sans-serif"><strong>AUM Capital Market (P) Ltd.</strong></h4><p style="Margin:0;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-family:arial, 'helvetica neue', helvetica, sans-serif;line-height:18px;color:#333333;font-size:12px">A one-stop solution for all your Financial needs</p><p style="Margin:0;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-family:arial, 'helvetica neue', helvetica, sans-serif;line-height:18px;color:#333333;font-size:12px"><br><a href="https://goo.gl/maps/NT3fReV9ZsYBVrkW9" target="_blank" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;text-decoration:underline;color:#3D85C6;font-size:12px">5, Lower Rawdon Street, Akashdeep, 1st Floor,</a><br>Kolkata - 700 020</p><p style="Margin:0;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-family:arial, 'helvetica neue', helvetica, sans-serif;line-height:18px;color:#333333;font-size:12px">Ph: +91 33 4057 2121 (Direct)</p><p style="Margin:0;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-family:arial, 'helvetica neue', helvetica, sans-serif;line-height:18px;color:#333333;font-size:12px"><a href="mailto:wealth@aumcap.com" target="_blank" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;text-decoration:underline;color:#3D85C6;font-size:12px">wealth@aumcap.com</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;<a href="http://www.aumcap.com/" target="_blank" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;text-decoration:underline;color:#3D85C6;font-size:12px">www.aumcap.com</a></p></td> 
                     </tr> 
                   </table></td> 
                 </tr> 
               </table></td> 
             </tr> 
           </table></td> 
         </tr> 
       </table></td> 
     </tr> 
   </table> 
  </div>  
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you share a sample sheet that contains your sample data. [Share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a [force-printed scriptlet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates#force-printing_scriptlets) (`<?!= body ?>`) to prevent the HTML from being escaped.

> [Y]ou’ll need to force-print if your scriptlet’s output intentionally contains HTML or scripts that you want to insert exactly as specified.